# Can't configure a clone of Crowd - /crowd/console/ Not Found

Tags: permissions, http-status-code-404, jira, crowd

I'm attempting to create an instance of Crowd, mirroring its Live counterpart for our Testing environment. I've cloned the container and changed some few key configuration, as described below. The problem is that while the URL loads this test version of Crowd, clicking "Set up Crowd" gives the following error:

[image]

The overall landing page looks oddly plain too, without nice-looking buttons and formatting, if that's any hint.

**Changes done since duplicating the container:**

1. Changed the hostname to test-crowd
2. `/var/crowd-home/crowd.properties` to specify test-crowd instead of crowd
3. `/opt/atlassian-crowd-2.11.1/apache-tomcat/conf/server.xml` to specify test-crowd instead of crowd
4. `/var/crowd-home/crowd.cfg.xml` to specify a test database instead of the live one
5. Modified `pg_hba.conf` on the test DB to allow test-crowd (this solved one error that was previously shown in catalina.out)
6. Fixed owner of `/opt/atlassian-crowd-2.11.1`, which was different from Live

**Output of catalina.out:** https://pastebin.com/GGiCrhPT
atlassian-crowd.log doesn't have a single line after the server was last stopped.
I have also verified that `crowd/console` exists with correct permissions in `/opt/atlassian-crowd-2.11.1/crowd-webapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/atlassian/crowd` just as it does in Live.

Does anyone have any ideas what to check and why this Crowd clone doesn't fully work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, even after strenuous comparison to similar resources that are served (such as the demo-webapp, located next to crowd-webapp), I couldn't find anything indicative of the problem.

I solved it by avoiding it - I just installed (simply unzipping and placing alongside) the newest version of Crowd 3.7.0 and this issue did not appear. Perhaps nobody has to deal with it unless they're running ancient versions :)